# Finding duplicate files

Tags: linux, bash

I need to write a bash script that finds duplicate files, but in addition to `md5sum` it needs to use `cmp` to do the final check. I tried the command below in my shell. How can I add a loop and put it into a bash script?

```
find . -type f | xargs -I%  md5sum % | sort | uniq -w32 -D| cut  -f3 -d' '
```

Comment: `md5sum` gives you a practical (though not theoretic) certainty of file identity. So, why do you want to consume time performing a further control?

Comment: because this is my homework and I have to check also with cmp

Comment: @el, you only want to to use `cmp` if the MD5 checksums are the same. Also, I would not try to do this in a one-liner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you state that this is homework, I'll give you a set of hints rather than a solution.

You can start with something like this:

```
find . -type f|xargs -I%  md5sum % |sort \
 |uniq -w32 -D|cut -f3 -d' '|while read filename ; do

   # code here

done
```

Inside this `while` loop, `filename` will contain the name of one of the files detected by your pipeline.

The idea is to compare each one with the previous files. To do that, at the end of the loop, add the current file to an array:

```
count=0
find . -type f|xargs -I%  md5sum % |sort \
 |uniq -w32 -D|cut -f3 -d' '|while read filename ; do

 # code here

 files[$cout]="$filename"
 count=$((count+1))
done
```

All you need now is to fill in `#code here` :-) You have at your disposal:

1. the file that needs comparing: `$filename`
2. the files it needs to be compared to: the `files` array
3. the number of files it should be compared against `$count` (watch out for off-by-one errors)

You can sort all this out with a `while` loop, comparing the files `$filename` and `${files[$some_counter]}` at each step.

---

To make this better, you should only check files with the same `md5sum` against each other. For that, you could:

1. remove the `cut` from your pipeline
2. change the `read` to read in both the md5 sum and the filename
3. reset the `files` array when you detect when you're moving on to another md5 sum

This will need one more variable to keep track of the "current" md5 sum.

---

You can make it even better by avoiding redundant comparisons. For that, you'll need to add a bit more logic to avoid adding a file to `files` if it is identical to one already in that array.

And you can do without the `$count` variable.

And something very important you should check (and fix if necessary): make sure your script works with filenames or directory names that contain spaces.

---

Read up on [bash arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).