# remove duplicates by renaming identical fles to same name

Tags: command-line, rename, filenames

I'm working with graphic design. I've downloaded many files (`EPS` files, `PSD` files, etc) from various websites.

Because it come from various websites, after downloaded from more than 10 different websites, I got many same files with same size, and same everything but different file name (2 to 4 copies for same file). To remove the duplication by manually open one by one is very time consuming

I hope there is a way to rename all downloaded files to be unique name for different files (I don't mind if the new name is not descriptive).

For example, 2 same file: file `nice-sun.eps` downloaded from site 1, while `678.eps` downloaded from site 2. It will become same file name after renamed.

Comment: You could use `md5sum` or `sha1sum` to identify duplicates.

Comment: This could help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/finding-duplicate-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This command will rename all files to the md5sum of their content. That means files with the same content will get the same name.

```
for f in *; do mv $f $(md5sum $f | cut -d " " -f 1); done
```

You can replace `md5sum` with `sha1sum` in the command.

For this demonstration I added `-v` to `mv` so we can see what is being renamed.

```
$ echo 1 > a
$ echo 2 > b
$ echo 1 > c
$ ls -1
a
b
c
$ for f in *; do mv -v $f $(md5sum $f | cut -d " " -f 1); done
`a' -> `b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1'
`b' -> `26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510'
`c' -> `b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1'
$ ls -1
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1
```

You can also safely run this command in a directory where some files have unified filename while other have not.

```
$ echo 1 > d
$ echo 2 > e
$ ls -1
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1
d
e
$ for f in *; do mv -v $f $(md5sum $f | cut -d " " -f 1); done
mv: `26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510' and `26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510' are the same file
mv: `b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1' and `b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1' are the same file
`d' -> `b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1'
`e' -> `26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510'
$ ls -1
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1
```

Note that it will still calculate the hash of the files that are already hashed. So if the files are huge you might want to prevent the rehashing.

Answer (score 4):

This is the `rename-hash` script I use to rename files to their hashsum, keeping the extension unchanged. Takes a list of files to be renamed as parameters. Use `-n` as first parameter for dry-run.

```
#!/bin/sh

unset DRY
[ "$1" == "-n" ] && { DRY=1; shift; }

for i in $@; do

if [ -f "$i" ]; then

HASHSUM=$(md5sum "$i" | sed 's/\(..........\).*/\1/')
DIR=$(dirname "$i")
BASE=$(basename "$i")
EXT=$(echo "$BASE" | sed -n 's/[^.]*\(\..*\)/\1/p')
TARGET="$DIR"/"$HASHSUM""$EXT"
if [ "$TARGET" != "$DIR/$BASE" ]; then
   if [ -n "$DRY" ]; then
       echo will rename "$i" to "$TARGET"
   else
       mv "$i" "$TARGET"
   fi
fi

fi

done
```

Example:

```
$ rename-hash -n *
will rename test.pdf to ./f604d0d6ad.pdf
will rename images.tar.gz to ./d41d8cd91b.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some utilities to find duplicates. You can use find and md5sum, but it can take a pretty long time.

I usually use [fdupes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes) for that. If can find all duplicates and output their names to stdout. After that you can parse output and rename all files as you want or even remove them.